# Error saving rules - Line 5: Expected '{'

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true,
".delete": true
}
}

these rules show me error Error saving rules - Line 5: Expected '{'.
Please help

Comment: Kindly share your entire set of rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database rules don't support a `".delete"` clause, and that's the reason you get this error message. Correct rules are:

```
{ 
  "rules": { 
    ".read": true, 
    ".write": true 
  } 
}
```

These rules will also allow deleting of the data, as part of the `.write` rule.

If you want to later disallow deletes or other types of updates, have a look at the documentation on [new data vs existing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#existing_data_vs_new_data).